# Nested If/Index/Match Statement that pulls data from other sheet not working in Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, index-match

I'm trying to check if an employee submitted a form within the two month period by matching month, year, and email.

Each individual If/Index/Match statement works individually, but when I combine both it only detects results from the first IF statement and not from the second IF statement.

What's wrong with this statement?

[sample google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oZcSigqQhOi0MgziaIx4A0rJ45e4B2o0p6UHu71tdLE/edit?usp=sharing)

`=IF(INDEX('SM Responses'!$J$2:$J,MATCH($D$1&$D$2&$F5,Month('SM Responses'!$A$2:$A)&Year('SM Responses'!$A$2:$A)&'SM Responses'!$J$2:$J,0))=$F5,"Completed",IF(INDEX('SM Responses'!$J$2:$J,MATCH($E$1&$D$2&$F5,Month('SM Responses'!$A$2:$A)&Year('SM Responses'!$A$2:$A)&'SM Responses'!$J$2:$J,0))=$F5,"Completed","No"))`

I tried using this formula to detect another sheet to determine if my employees submitted a checkin form within one of the two months (Sept/Oct). I used IF/Index/Match to try to detect either months form but for some reason it only detects the first months (Sept) data and not the second month. Both of the Index/Match statement works individually but doesn't work correctly when combined.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach you can try in `Cell I4`

```
=if(iserror(filter('SM Responses'!J:J,'SM Responses'!J:J=F4,
(eomonth('SM Responses'!A:A,)=eomonth(date(D$2,D$1,1),))+(eomonth('SM Responses'!A:A,)=eomonth(date(D$2,E$1,1),)))),"No","Completed")
```